# multidimensional json encoded associative array php to JS

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, arrays, json

Hi initially my array looked something like this

PHP

```
$results = array(
    "banana" => $bananavalue,
    "apple" => $applevalue,
);
echo json_encode($results);
```

JS

```
var fruits = [];
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: "actions/MYphp.php",
  data: PassArray,
  dataType: 'json',
  beforeSend: function (html) {
    //    alert(html);
  },
  success: function (html) {
    var obj = html;
    // Now the two will work
    $.each(obj, function (key, value) {
      fruits.push([key, value]);
    });
```

However I would like to change it to a multidimensional of fruits and vegetable per the below:

```
results = array(
    "fruit"=>array(
        "banana" => $bananavalue,
        "apple" => $applevalue
    ),
    "vegetables"=>array(
        "lettuce" => $lettuce,
        "cabbage" => $cabbage
    )
);
echo json_encode($results);
```

The question is how can I loop in each array in Javascript and assign it to two arrays.(fruits and vegetables)

I have tried

```
$.each(obj['fruit'], function(key, value) {
  fruits.push([key, value]);
});
```

But that didn't work.

Comment: when you say it didn't work, in what way did it not work?

Comment: PHP associative arrays json-decode to javascript objects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unlike PHP, javascript doesn't have associative arrays.

JSON-encoded PHP associative arrays decode to javascript plain objects.

To access the data in javascript :

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "actions/MYphp.php",
    data: PassArray,
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(obj) {
        //do whatever is required with obj.fruits and obj.vegetables here
    };
});
```

In general, you won't want to assign `obj` or `obj.fruits` or `obj.vegetables` to members in an outer scope as they are not usable until the ajax response has arrived. You will typically do everything necessary with `obj.fruits` and `obj.vegetables` in the `success` scope (and functions called therefrom).

Comment: Thanks very good answer.Sorry I can't upvote (not enough reputation)

Comment: Athanatos, if/when you are ready to do so, you should be able to accept the answer (big green tick).

Answer (score 0):

do it the similar way as you would do in PHP, nest 2 loops.

```
$.each(obj, function(keyOfOuterArray, innerArray) {
   // keyOfOuterArray equals to vegetables, fruit
   console.log(keyOfOuterArray); 

   $.each(innerArray, function(keyOfInnerArray, valueOfInnerArray) {
     //valueOfInnerArrayis your inner array value
     console.log(keyOfInnerArray, valueOfInnerArray); 
   });
});
```

to answer your question do this:

```
var myNewObj = {};
$.each(obj, function(keyOfOuterArray, innerArray) {
   $.each(innerArray, function(keyOfInnerArray, valueOfInnerArray) {
      myNewObj[keyOfOuterArray][keyOfInnerArray] = valueOfInnerArray;
   });
});
```

Comment: Why? All the data needed is already in `obj`. It's ready to use. All you've done is make a copy of it. If you really need a copy then use jQuery's `$.extend()`.